# Magento2.4.6 sftp cannot access /var/www/html, how to modify the permissions of html files

Tags: magento2.4.6

I installed magento2.4.6 on Ubuntu22.04. I don't know much about folder permissions, and now I can't login to /var/www/html files using sftp. How can I solve this problem?

【FileZilla】

```
Status: Listing directory /var/www
Status: Directory listing of "/var/www" successful
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/var/www/html"...
Command:    cd "html"
Error:  Directory /var/www/html: permission denied
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

[image]

【SSH】

```
root@ip-123-45-6-78:/var/www# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 Apr 21 07:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root     4096 Apr 21 07:34 ..
drwx--x--x 12 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 21 14:23 html
root@ip-123-45-6-78/var/www#
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an online tool to convert file permissions between formats, eg chmod-calculator.com

Currently, your chmod for `/var/www/html` is `drwx--x--x` = 711.
You should change permission for it to 775 = `drwxrwxr-x`

```
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html
```

To enable the web server to write files and directories in the file system but to also maintain ownership by the file system owner, both users must be in the same group. This is necessary so both users can share access to files (including files created using the Admin or other web-based utilities).

To put the file system owner in the web server’s primary group (assuming the typical Apache group name for CentOS and Ubuntu), enter the following command as a user with root privileges:

- `CentOS: usermod -a -G apache <username>`
- `Ubuntu: usermod -a -G www-data <username>`

Eg, you are using Ubuntu and have `ubuntu` as an existing user, run:
`usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu`

For more configure file ownership and permissions:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/file-system/configure-permissions.html?lang=en

Comment: The default user is Ubuntu, and the permissions cannot be modified. After I switch to the root user, I can modify the permissions.

Now I can open the html folder.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help @Angelo

Comment: But I can't make any modifications to the file.

Comment: @Angelo try to follow the document from Magento to set permission for files and directories inside your Magento directory (`/var/www/html`): https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/deployment/file-system-permissions.html?lang=en

Comment: It's an Ubuntu admin (here is ubuntu or root) rights issue, and I've found a workaround. Please see here. 
https://repost.aws/questions/QUBt8ZgC76Rt6kDkzcqWlTGA/magento2-4-6-sftp-cannot-access-var-www-html-how-to-modify-the-permissions-of-html-files

Comment: @Angelo Great! The document I sent above (Magento official document) already mentioned that: "To enable the web server to write files and directories in the file system but to also maintain ownership by the file system owner, both users must be in the same group. This is necessary so both users can share access to files (including files created using the Admin or other web-based utilities)."... Ubuntu: `usermod -a -G www-data <username>`. So, I'll add it to my answer to help other who has the same issue come here in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The default user is ubuntu, and the permissions cannot be modified. After I switch to the root user, I can modify the permissions.

Now I can open the html folder.

But I can't make any modifications to the file.

```
Status: Starting upload of F:\Magento\theme\themeforest-TlWf1t1h-minimogmgt-the-high-converting-magento-2-theme\Minimog_Package_1.1.9\Base_Start_Package\minimog_theme\minimog_theme.zip
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/var/www/html"...
Status: Listing directory /var/www/html
Command:    put "F:\Magento\theme\themeforest-TlWf1t1h-minimogmgt-the-high-converting-magento-2-theme\Minimog_Package_1.1.9\Base_Start_Package\minimog_theme\minimog_theme.zip" "minimog_theme.zip"
Error:  /var/www/html/minimog_theme.zip: open for write: permission denied
Error:  File transfer failed
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/var/www/html"...
Status: Listing directory /var/www/html
Status: Directory listing of "/var/www/html" successful
Status: Disconnected from server
```

[image]

```
ubuntu@ip-123-45-6-78:~$ chmod 775 -R /var/www/html
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/www/html': Operation not permitted
chmod: cannot read directory '/var/www/html': Permission denied
ubuntu@ip-123-45-6-78:~$ su root
Password:
root@ip-123-45-6-78:/home/ubuntu# cd /
root@ip-123-45-6-78:/# chmod 775 -R /var/www/html
root@ip-123-45-6-78:/# cd /var/www
root@ip-123-45-6-78:/var/www# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 Apr 21 07:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root     4096 Apr 21 07:34 ..
drwxrwxr-x 12 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 21 14:23 html
root@ip-123-45-6-78:/var/www#
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's an Ubuntu admin (here is ubuntu or root) rights issue, and I've found a workaround. Please see here.
https://repost.aws/questions/QUBt8ZgC76Rt6kDkzcqWlTGA/magento2-4-6-sftp-cannot-access-var-www-html-how-to-modify-the-permissions-of-html-files